# Primefaces chart is not working in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to implement Primefaces chart in JSF page. Unfortunately the code is not working. I get just simple JSF page without chart:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> Account Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>
        </div>  
        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_dashboard.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:lineChart value="#{DashboardController.linearModel}" legendPosition="e" zoom="true" animate="true"
                                     title="Linear Chart" minY="0" maxY="10" style="width:400px;" widgetVar="chart"/>

                        <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{DashboardController.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne"
                                    title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0" max="200" style="width:400px" animate="true"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdiva" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:400px">

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/* include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 


import org.primefaces.model.chart.CartesianChartModel;  
import org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries;  
import org.primefaces.model.chart.LineChartSeries;

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@Named("DashboardController")
@SessionScoped
public class Dashboard implements Serializable {


    /* Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver */
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;



    private CartesianChartModel linearModel;

    private CartesianChartModel categoryModel;

    public Dashboard() {
        createLinearModel();
        createCategoryModel();
    }

    public CartesianChartModel getLinearModel() {
        return linearModel;
    }

    public CartesianChartModel getCategoryModel() {
        return categoryModel;
    }

    private void createLinearModel() {
        linearModel = new CartesianChartModel();

        LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();
        series1.setLabel("Series 1");

        series1.set(1, 2);
        series1.set(2, 1);
        series1.set(3, 3);
        series1.set(4, 6);
        series1.set(5, 8);

        LineChartSeries series2 = new LineChartSeries();
        series2.setLabel("Series 2");
        series2.setMarkerStyle("diamond");

        series2.set(1, 6);
        series2.set(2, 3);
        series2.set(3, 2);
        series2.set(4, 7);
        series2.set(5, 9);

        linearModel.addSeries(series1);
        linearModel.addSeries(series2);
    }

    private void createCategoryModel() {
        categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();

        ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
        boys.setLabel("Boys");

        boys.set("2004", 120);
        boys.set("2005", 100);
        boys.set("2006", 44);
        boys.set("2007", 150);
        boys.set("2008", 25);

        ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();
        girls.setLabel("Girls");

        girls.set("2004", 52);
        girls.set("2005", 60);
        girls.set("2006", 110);
        girls.set("2007", 135);
        girls.set("2008", 120);

        categoryModel.addSeries(boys);
        categoryModel.addSeries(girls);
    }
}
```

I implemented the example from Primefaces web site examples. I don't find any error messages in Glassfish log. Can you help me to solve the problem?

P.S I successfully can use Primefaces growl into the bundle. Maybe this is Primefaces bug?

Comment: try wrapping the charts with `h:form`

Comment: I tested `<h:form>` it's not working.

Comment: make the bean `@ManagedBean(name = "DashboardController")` instead of `@Named("DashboardController")` and use `import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`

Comment: I want to use CDI beans. If I implement JSF beans I cannot use CDI.

Comment: make this test to see where the problem is coming from...

Comment: I get this error stack when I try to deploy it: http://pastebin.com/Qk9T7b4d

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this old question:

If you want to use Primefaces Dashboard along with cdi, then you have to use:

```
@Named // from javax.inject.Named

@ViewScoped // from javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
```

Hope this helps.